# I upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and touch-pad stopped working in HP pavilion 15 r062tu

Tags: upgrade, hp-touchpad

The touchpad is even not detected. But regular mouse is working fine.

**xinput list**

```
Virtual core pointer                            id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems touchpad file need to enabled, please try the below command and check whether it works,

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse

sudo modprobe psmouse proto=XXX
```

In the place of XXX you can fill your name as your wish to give to touchpad.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: jais@jais:~/workspace$ sudo modprobe psmouse proto=touchpad
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'psmouse': Invalid argument